# fabricator with hstore attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, hstore, fabrication-gem

I am trying to build a fabricator using 'fabrication', '2.8.1' with a hstore attribute.

```
Fabricator(:inventory_item_change) do
  attribute_changes Hash.new("num_units" => "to:50")
  state "scheduled"
  change_code 1
  execution_at Time.now.advance(days: 3)
  inventory_item
end
```

This is the error message I am receiving when running tests with this fabricator.  I've isolated the problem to be the hstore attribute: attribute changes.

```
 Failure/Error: attr = Fabricate.attributes_for(:inventory_item_change)
 ArgumentError:
   bad value for range
```

Can anyone assist in identifying the correct syntax, or another suitable solution for fabricating objects with hstore attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at the following issue at on github:
https://github.com/paulelliott/fabrication/issues/202

It seems as though you can't directly pass the hash in as it is then treated as an options argument.

The correct syntax for you would be:

```
Fabricator(:inventory_item_change) do
 attribute_changes do
    { "num_units" => "to:50"}
 end
 state "scheduled"
 change_code 1
 execution_at Time.now.advance(days: 3)
 inventory_item
end
```