# Fabricating hstore values for Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, rspec, sequel, hstore, fabrication-gem

As in title, I try to fabricate hash into hstore type column.

I have seen question [fabricator with hstore attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23769399/fabricator-with-hstore-attribute), but the solution there does not work for me.

My hstore column name is "status", there I want to set three flags: "processed", "duplicate", "eol". I'm using sequel (4.14.0) as ORM, fabrication (2.8.1), Ruby 2.1.2 and Postgresql of course ;)

**case 1:**

```
status {eol: true, duplicate: false, processed: true}
```

result:

> syntax error

**case 2:**

```
status {"heol"=>"true", "hduplicate"=>"false", "hprocessed"=>"true"}
```

result:

> syntax error

**case 3:**

```
  status do
    {"heol"=>"true", "hduplicate"=>"false", "hprocessed"=>"true"}
  end
```

result:

> Sequel::DatabaseError:
>          PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "status" is of type hstore but expression is of type boolean
>          LINE 1: ...23.0, '2000-01-01', (('heol' = '...
>          HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

**case 4:**

```
status do
    {status: "heol:true"}
  end
```

result:

> Failure/Error: Fabricate(:entry)
>        Sequel::DatabaseError:
>          PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "status" does not exist
>          LINE 1: ...123.0, '2000-01-01', ("status" =...
>          HINT:  There is a column named "status" in table "entries", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.

**case 5:**

> status do
>       {'status' => "heol:true"}   end

result:

> ```
> Failure/Error: Fabricate(:entry)
>  Sequel::DatabaseError:
>    PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "status" is of type hstore but expression is of type boolean
>    LINE 1: ...123.0, '2000-01-01', ('status' =...
>    HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
> ```

**case 6:**
gave up ;)
result:
this question

With FactoryGirl everything works as expected, and syntax is straightforward:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :entry do
    status {{ flag_processed: true, flag_duplicate: false }}
end
```

Promise to make good use of the correct syntax in Fabrication =)
Thanks!

Lucas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 1 and 2 are definitely not what you want. The Hash needs to be specified within a block, which is the same as what FactoryGirl is doing with your example containing double braces. Case 3, 4, and 5 would normally work but don't because Sequel has a special syntax for assigning hstore columns and Fabrication is not automatically translating it for you (because before you brought it up I had no idea this was a thing).

If you change it to this, I think you'll find success:

```
status do
  Sequel.hstore("heol"=>"true", "hduplicate"=>"false", "hprocessed"=>"true")
end
```

Comment: Just a note: to use Sequel.hstore method you need to enable Sequel's pg_hstore extension on your database instance (DB):
DB.extension :pg_hstore